# Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM

Tags: sql

необходимо вывести список пациентов с указанием их лечащих врачей,
схема базы приведена ниже.

[image: Схема базы]

Пишу следующий запрос:

```
SELECT PATIENS.NAME, DOCTORS.NAME
FROM VISITS
JOIN PATIENTS ON PATIENTS.PATIENTID = VISITS.VISITPATIENTID
JOIN DOCTORS ON DOCTORS.DOCTORID = VISITS.VISITDOCTORID
```

Но ловлю ошибку:

## Ошибка синтаксиса в предложении FROM.

Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

Comment: поля в select для начала правильно укажите, нет там `name` на схеме

Comment: @teran, да и таблицы или алиаса PATIENS тоже

Comment: Спасибо)))000))

Comment: @Grundy это да. вообще, конечно, странное сообщение для ошибки, это все же не ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: Это часом не MS Access?

Comment: Было бы не лишним также добавить DISTINCT; select DISTINCT ...